# Saving entities related by foreign key (POST/PUT Request) in Entity Framework, ASP.NET-MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have two classes that are related by a one-to-many relationship. A Category can have multiple Products, a Product can only have a single Category.

### Models

Models/Category.cs:

```
namespace Projeto.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get ; set; }
        public ICollection<CategoryCategory> CategoryParent { get; set; } 
        public ICollection<CategoryCategory> CategoryChild { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Models/Product.cs:

```
namespace Projeto.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

### The issue

When I execute a POST or PUT, trying to update the 'category' of a given product, the following error returns:

Request Body (HttpPut):

```
{
    "productId": 1,
    "name": "testing",
    "category": 1
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "category": [
        "Error converting value 1 to type 'Projeto.Models.Category'. Path 'category', line 4, position 15."
    ]
}
```

### Possible solutions

I have tried multiple combinations of the 'virtual' data-type, which I've seen solves this issue, but could never fix the error and make the CRUD operations function as expected. I have also tried the [ForeignKey] data annotation, again with no luck:

```
public int CategoryMetaID;
[ForeignKey("CategoryMetaID")]
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

Admittedly, I don't have much knowledge regarding C#, ASP.NET MVC or the Entity Framework itself, so this might be a really rookie mistake. I have, however, managed to setup a working API that can POST and UPDATE many-to-many relationships (Product has Product), but can't seem to fix this ony-to-many foreign key relationship issue.

Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to provide the api and the code that you update the db. here you just provided the models and that is not enough info to find the problem

Comment: The controller containing the code that updates the database is generated through scaffolding. HttpPut snippet: https://pastebin.com/yNVBinbi

Answer (score 3):

it's clear that in following

```
{
"productId": 1,
"name": "testing",
"category": 1
}
```

**"category": 1** can't bind to a object of type Category

```
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

So to correct this error you have to know that web api use json fomatter to parse the incoming objects to C# POCO objects. this is the Json.Net library

so you can tag this property to ignore when binding using following

```
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

Standered way to do this is put following on Product class witch is the foreign key and add it in the Category class

Change Product Class and add this

```
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

Change Category class and add this

```
[ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get ; set; }
```

i think this will help you. please try it

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When sending the same PUT request as described in the question, I get the following error: SqlException: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Product_Category_CategoryMetaID". The conflict occurred in database "ProjectContextDatabase", table "dbo.Category", column 'CategoryID'.

Any idea on how to edit the modelBuilder of the 'products' entity to set it to UPDATE/DELETE on cascade when updated?

Comment: Tell me what exactly you going to update? you trying to update a product or insert one? by default cascade update and delete is turn on in EF and you can turn that off if you want.

Comment: I am trying to update the 'category' field or an existing 'product'.

Comment: iirc, json formatter will input default values if sender underpost. So in this case, if I leave out category, the json formatter will bind null to the reference type; again, iirc, if one wants to update or add a foreign key, it sufficies to fill in only the foreign key attribute and leave out the object reference. In this case, as far as EF is concerned, one can just fill in the categoryId and leave the Category blank, if, of course, EF is made aware of the foreign key categoryId. The question, however, is whether this is a best practice or not?